# PNPM install did work but ProdBuild is failing

Tags: npm, pnpm

I've used pnpm install and it did work for me. But when doing ProdBuild it failed:

[image: Error screenshot]

For the same project earlier using npm install and npm run ProdBuild worked without having any issues. But doing a prod build using pnpm is failing. Can someone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use Angular. Angular projects currently work only when `shamefully-hoist` is `true`. You can create a `.npmrc` file in the root of your project and put `shamefully-hoist=true` there. Then reinstall the dependencies with `pnpm install`.

Also, if typescript is not in you dependencies, you may have to install it with `pnpm add -D typescript`

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I've implemented the same but still i came across another iss            ERROR in ./node_modules/.pnpm/repo1.uhc.com/@angular/router/8.2.14_e9fbe5720e9434eb9ae0f6720f1ca3f4/node_modules/@angular/router/router.ngfactory.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/.pnpm/repo1.uhc.com/@ngtools/webpack/8.3.25_b710e183f59e4f8b337ec71435ef0473/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):

Comment: Could you create a repository on GitHub where I can reproduce this?